# how to create report which do following in salesforce

Tags: reporting

I want a report which shows no. of lead status with respect to role name.

suppose Sale rep have.

open - 3
working -2
close -5

Answer (score 1):

Create a Lead Report , groupby User Role and then Lead Status will show you record Count. For convenient display user Matrix Report.

Comment: I want record count as a column.